# How to make multiple operation in ifPresent with Optional on Java?

Tags: java, spring, java-stream, option-type, optional-chaining

What I do is simply user can do trade but first I need to check balance of accounts(usdt & bitcoin account). Simple thing is that for buying I only check usdt account balance and for selling I only check crypto balance but the problem is that these accounts can be null too, thats why I need to use Optional.

Here is my comparing code;

```
private boolean isBalanceAvailableForTrade(TradeRequestDto requestDto, List<Account> accountList) {
        Optional<Account> dollarAccount = accountList.stream()
                .filter(account -> account.getAccountCurrencyType().equals(Currency.USDT.toString()))
                .findFirst();
        Optional<Account> cryptoAccount = accountList.stream()
                .filter(account -> account.getAccountCurrencyType().equals(requestDto.getCurreny()))
                .findFirst();

        if (requestDto.getOperationType().equalsIgnoreCase(BUY)) {
            if (dollarAccount.get().getAmount().compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0)) > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            //TODO throw no available amount exception etc.
            return false;
        }
        if (requestDto.getOperationType().equalsIgnoreCase(SELL)) {
            if(cryptoAccount.get().getAmount().compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0)) > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            //TODO throw no available amount exception etc.
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My problem is actually I am not checking if the accounts are null above, the line

```
`if (dollarAccount.get().getAmount().compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0)) > 0)` may throw *NullPointerException*.
```

I need something like :

```
dollarAccount.ifPresent(()-> {then do multiple line of code/operation} ).orElseThrow(some exception)
```

I am pretty near to solution I think but I cannot figure out how to implement Optional for multiple check(balance check and null check). How should I refactor this piece of code properly ?

**Side note:** I am not sure if the following account check is also best practice or not and if you can give suggestion, it is more than welcome

```
Optional<Account> dollarAccount = accountList.stream()
                    .filter(account -> account.getAccountCurrencyType().equals(Currency.USDT.toString()))
                    .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to extract the logic of finding an account and getting its balance into a separate method. It'll make the code more cohesive and concise.

Method **getAmount()** returns a BigDecimal and there's **no need to deal with the Optional** inside **isBalanceAvailableForTrade()** at all.

Hence you are OK with throwing the exception in the case if an account for the given currency isn't found it's better to make use of the **orElseThrow()** inside the **getAmount()** method, rather than bother will optional object downstream in the call chain.

> problem is actually I am not checking if the accounts are null

To avoid NPE it's enough to add one more filter to a stream (take a look at **getAmount()** method), and it has to be the first operation in the pipeline.

```
private boolean isBalanceAvailableForTrade(TradeRequestDto requestDto, List<Account> accountList) {
        BigDecimal dollarAccAmount = getAmount(accountList, Currency.USDT.toString());
        BigDecimal cryptoAccAmount = getAmount(accountList, requestDto.getCurreny());

        if (requestDto.getOperationType().equalsIgnoreCase(BUY)) {
            if (dollarAccAmount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            throw new NoAvailableAmountException();
        }
        if (requestDto.getOperationType().equalsIgnoreCase(SELL)) {
            if (cryptoAccAmount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            throw new NoAvailableAmountException();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```
    private BigDecimal getAmount(List<Account> accountList, String currency) {
        return accountList.stream()
                .filter(account -> account != null)
                .filter(account -> account.getAccountCurrencyType().equals(currency))
                .findFirst()
                .map(Account::getAmount)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("unable to find an Account for currency " + currency));
    }
```

> I need something like :
>
> dollarAccount.ifPresent(()-> {then do multiple line of code/operation}
> ).orElseThrow(some exception)

For this purpose Optional class has been provided with methods **filter()**, **map()**, **flatMap()**. And since Java 9 we have **stream()** which create either an empty stream or a stream with a single element. That allows you to chain mapping and filtering operations on the optional object as much as you need or turn optional into a stream.

Please, note that operation **map(accountList::getAmount)** inside the method **getAmount()** is invoked **not** on the element of the stream, but on the **Optional** object, returned  by the terminal operation findFirst().

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#method.summary

Comment: @abidinberkay There is a typo, replace it with Account::getAmount

Answer (score 2):

`.orElseThrow()` returns the contained value, so you just use it instead of `.get()`:

```
dollarAccount.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception()).getAmount().compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0)) > 0
```

Maybe just split it up, so that it doesn't get too long (and possibly drop the `if`):

```
Account account = dollarAccount.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception());
return account.getAmount().compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0)) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using `get` on an `Optional`. You can unpack an optional using `orElseThrow` as follows:

```
Account account = dollarAccount.orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Dollar account not found!));
```

This will either return an `Account` or throw an exception if the optinal is emtpy.

For your side note:

Your stream looks correct, it will return an empty optinal if `accountList` is empty or if the `filter` would not find any account. Otherwise, the filtering will stop at the first account found.